# How to replace an item in a listbox Lazarus

Tags: replace, listbox, lazarus

My question is how do i replace an item in a listbox in Lazarus from a button procedure?

I know how to add and delete an item thats selected within the listbox but how do i remove the selected item and then add another item in the same place as the old one without changing its position in the listbox.

Example:

> Bowl
>   Collar
>   Large pack of chews
>   Medium pack of chews
>   Pet grooming kit
>   Tick shampoo
>   Vitamin supplement

If i wanted to remove 'Collar' from the listbox and replace it with another item like 'Cat food' and have Cat food in the second index position.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know that the index is `1` then you can replace that item's text with a simple assignment:

```
  ListBox1.Items[1] := 'Cat food';
```

Comment: Maybe in addition: At first you must find the index of the 'Collar' item which you can get by calling Listbox1.Items.Indexof('Collar')

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers ive got it to work, if i may can i ask how do i display an item from a listbox in another listbox, so if i wanted 'Collar' from listbox1 to display in a sentence in listbox2.

Comment: You know how to read and write items from a list box. You know how to add and delete them. Surely you can use that knowledge to solve your next problem.